# Can't read RTSP in Mediamtx server

Tags: rtsp

i stuck with simple task: I have some RTSP stream, I want to read it with [mediamtx](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx).
My config file is:

```
  paths:
    cam1:
       source: rtsp://zephyr.rtsp.stream/pattern?streamKey=87a01fc49801f9771ecd0bb7666d6c04
```

The stream is active and I can watch it with VLC player.

I got:

`closed: no one is publishing to path 'cam1'`

Tested with several 100% working RSTP streams and still getting this errror.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I get an error:
`ERR [path cam01] [RTSP source] EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to gather all the logs you can and post it as an issue on the official mediamtx repo.

With what you've provided your chances of getting good answer are slim.